# Nivel de compatibilidad SQL y azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

Resulta que en azure tengo una Base de datos que quiero hacerle una copia de seguridad en mi ordenador local, y quiero generar un archivo .bacpac, pero me pone el siguiente error.

ya intente

```
ALTER DATABASE name_db SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
GO
```

ayuda por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]